# Jenkins remove inprogress build on BitBucket if it's not built

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

To save resources on our Jenkins server we abort intermediate builds if a newer commit is available.

Now BitBucket stays on "In Progress" forever for this intermediate commit. If this intermediate commit is the head on another branch we can't merge.

How can you remove the inprogress notification? I don't want to set the intermediate build to successful if it isn't built. I also don't want to set it to failure because that's also not true, I want to abort the build and remove the inprogress state.

According to https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/ there's only 3 states. But I want to remove the specified key completely, as if the build never happened.

Comment: Looking at docs you provided - there seems to be no way to do what you want. There's no `DELETE` action nor `NOT_BUILT` or similar state :(

Comment: Totally different approach: I have never seen a way of working where a build is cancelled. What I normally see is a timeout/delay. So build will be queued for max couple of minutes to wait for a bulk of commit pushes. A cancelled build is still wasted resourcess. Did a lot of effort but no end result. What is the total time of a jenkins build/test?

Comment: @RvdK total time is 15 minutes + whatever wait time we have if too many other jobs are queued.

Comment: Canceled builds is faster for developer feedback. Queuing is good too, but continuing a queued build even if don't care about that information is also wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to ignore the INPROGRESS state and simply notify Bitbucket with either SUCCESS or FAILURE at the end of builds. Since you have no way of determining upfront which build would have another commit pushed before the pipeline is done executing.

Comment: That's pretty much what we did back in the day. Sadly no better interface. But we've moved on from BitBucket now :).

Comment: sadly! I currently am facing the opposite, I send an INPROGRESS state but there's no visual cue for it, until build succeeds or fails before an icon is displayed, that's how I stumbled on this question.

Comment: Hm, interesting, can't check right now, but for me INPROGRESS always showed up right away with an icon.